# How to stop the Windows Command Prompt from opening older version of Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

I just started learning to code. I am following along the Python 4 Everyone videos on YouTube. After you installed Python and Atom you write a basic Hello World program in a file and use the Windows Command Prompt to open the file. This works perfectly.

Now the next exercise I did in place of the Hello World program. Meaning I erased the previous line of code and wrote the new program. I saved it. But when I tried to execute it on the Windows Command Prompt again, it still ran the previous version of the file (The Hello World One).

I tried to close the command prompt and the file and then restart the process but to no avail. I Googled but they only give tips on how to restore previous versions of the file. (I may be Googling wrong since I do not have the proper vocabulary to pinpoint the problem.)

Okay so on the command prompt I wrote (from the beginning):

```
dir
cd desktop/py4e
python first.py
```

Py4e is the folder on the desktop which opens the file called first. This works but not the way I want. Its result is 'Hello World from the File'.

The previous code from the file was:

```
print('Hello World from the File.')
```

The current code from the file is:

```
eurfloor = input('What floor is it in Europe?')
eurfloor = int(eurfloor) + 1
print('It is floor',str(eurfloor),'in America')
```

I Googled, I saved, I restarted, I did everything I thought would help. Any advice or specific wording I can research?

Comment: It sounds like either you're looking at the wrong file, or your IDE hasn't committed the changes you made to the disk. I'd check the first possibility, as it's the most likely. We've all done it.

Comment: If you open the file with a simple text editor (e.g. notepad) can you confirm that it is the new version of the file?

Answer (score 0):

What happened was I renamed the folder on my desktop but the IDE didn't update the folder name. The folder was first called 'Python Files' but I renamed it 'Py4E'. Atom still opened Python Files/first.py and the changes were therefore committed there.

Thanks for the comments that resulted in me investigating whether the right file was opened.